# url does not decode properly with request[] in C#

Tags: c#, url, request

I have an object like this:

```
public class adapterContext {
    public HttpRequest Request;
}
adapterContext ac = new adapterContext();
ac.Response = context.Response;
```

I pass this object to my functions and use ac.Request[""] to get my url variables. However this somehow does not translate national/special characters correct. When I use f.ex this as part of the URL: prospectName=Tester+%e6+%f8+%e5

I get "Tester ? ? ?"

From the debugger I get: ac.Request["prospectName"][7]  65533 '�'   char

Anyone have any idea how I should fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a nice function, you should take care of: [HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) ...
otherwise you need to adjust the [globalization setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) in your web.config (requestEncoding, responseEncoding ...)

Comment: Btw, firebug shows that the valid encoding should be UTF-8 witch should be de default, so globalization and urlDecode should not be needed.

Comment: i suggest you use certain umlauts which aren't escaped. have you ever tried something like iso-8859-1?? you have 2 choices: either you set the globalization to your encoding, or you pass the values proper decoded

Comment: After having debugged a while I found the web application to switch encoding more or less in the middle of calls. This was apparently caused by a ajax POST, once I switched to GET it AND set the encoding to iso-8859-1 it worked.

Comment: One of the other weird things I noticed was that using Firefox on my development machine and url containing ÆØÅ (not escaped) worked fine. While using the same URL/browser on the prod platformed got me ???. I also noticed that UrlEncode with utf-8 was diffrent from the iso-8859-1 encode.

Comment: I think the correct solution would be to do UTF-8 urlEncode in the first place, unfortantly this is not as easy as it has to be done inside a SQL server trigger...

Comment: decoding is indeed a bit weird: some browser switch the encoding to the encoding of the server and not the encoding for the specific page...